# How to beat delays in UDP client

Tags: c++, winapi, udp

I'm trying to write a UDP client App, which receives some control packets(length 52-104 bytes) from a server fragmented to datagrams of size 1-4 bytes each (Why this is not a big packet and is fragmented instead? That's a mystery to me...).

I created a thread, and in this thread I used a typical `recvfrom` example from MS. The received data from the small buffer I append to string to recreate the packet (If the packet is too big, the string would be cleared).

My problem is the latency:
The inbound packets are changed, but the data from the buffer and the string hasn't changed during the minute or more. I tried to use a circular buffer instead of a string, but it has no effect on the latency.

So, what am I doing wrong and how do I receive a fragmented UDP packet in a proper way?

I don't have the original sender code, so i'm attaching a part of my sender emulator. As you can see, the original data string (mSendString) is fragmented to some four-bytes packets and sent to the net. When the data string has changed on sender side, the data on receiver side hasn't changed in aceptable time, it changed a few minutes later.

```cs
UdpClient mSendClient = new UdpClient();
string mSendString = "head,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,chksumm\n";//Control string
public static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            UdpClient u = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;

            mMsgSent = true;
        }

public void Send()
        {
            while (!mThreadStop)
            {
                if (!mSendStop)
                {                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < mSendString.Length; i+=4)
                    {
                        Byte[] sendBytes = new Byte[4];
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mSendString,i,4,sendBytes,0);
                        mSendClient.BeginSend(sendBytes, 1, mEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), mSendClient);                        
                    }

                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The question you should be asking is why your packets are so horribly fragmented. And maybe show your code.

Comment: @zx485 You guess wrong. IP does the reassembly, and only when it has a complete datagram will the application even see it. The application couldn't reassemble fragments even if it wanted to.

Comment: The server is sending those datagrams in those tiny sizes. Show the sending code.

Comment: I suspect the presence of some code erroneously using `sizeof(some_pointer)` in an attempt to specify a packet size in bytes, but actually ending up with 4 bytes as the value instead.

Comment: Thanks you, i udpdated question with the sender code

Comment: Exactly as stated. You are sending four bytes at a time. Solution: don't.

Comment: @user207421 Okay, i fix the my sender emulation, now it send one datagram with four characters from string per time period, that i set(20 ms for example). Still no effect. May be i asked a wrong question...

Comment: If you send four-byte datagrams you will receive four-byte datagrams. But that's not what you said you were attempting to do above. This is not 'fragmentation' at all, it is correct execution of your program. You need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong when I asked this question in some points:

- First,the wrong terms - the string was chopped/sliced/divided into
  four bytes packets, not fragmented.
- Second, I was thought, that too
  much small UDP packets are the cause of latency in my app, but when I
  ran my UDP receive code separately from other app code, I found this
  UDP receive code is working without latency.

Seems like there are threading problems, not UDP sockets.